# How to initialize a 'NotNull' Array of a class in c# without loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I want to have something like:

```
class Main{
   SomeClass[] classArray = new SomeClass[199];   // Problem --> All elements are null
   for(int i=0; i<classArray.Length; i++){
      classArray[i] = new SomeClass();
   }
}

class SomeClass{
   int x = 1;
   public SomeClass(){}
}
```

but without loop and without doing something like:

```
SomeClass[] classArray = new SomeClass[] {new SomeClass(), new SomeClass(), ...}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Consider using `List<T>`.

Comment: With using List<T> i also have to use a loop to add a fixed number of elements or am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range` method will generate collection of integers in the given range.
`Select` method will create new instance for every number.
`ToArray` will enumerate generated collection and create an array

```
var yourArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 199).Select(i => new SomeClass()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Jonesopolis,  `Repeat` will create array with same instance of `SomeClass`

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

That's not really possible.  You can do several things that result in loops, but don't quite look like loops.  For example:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 199)
           .Select(_ => new SomeClass())
           .ToList();
```